# How to send -d information in rest assured?

Tags: java, rest, curl, rest-assured

I am trying to automate an api which has -d information which needs to be sent.

curl request looks like this-

`curl -X PUT "https://XXXXXXX.com/v1/YOLO/cccc/abc/mom" -H "accept: */*" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[10035]"`

I am not able to sent `-d "[10035]"` this part in the request.

Needs to be done restAssured and this is what I was trying-

```
RequestSpecification request = given().filter(new RequestLoggingFilter(requestCapture));
        Response response =  request.auth().basic(XXX,XXX).body(Arrays.asList("10017")).contentType("application/json")
                .put(Chttps://XXXXXXX.com/v1/YOLO/cccc/abc/mom").then().extract()
                .response();
```

I appreciate your help.

Comment: As per CURL documentation, -d is used to send post data in the body, just use body("[10035]")

Comment: I have tried this, but didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
 curl --data-raw "[10035]" https://example.com
```